# Forecasting From an Age-based Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, forecasting, prediction

I have an age-based probability distribution that looks something like this, where the age is in rows, and the year is in columns:

```
Age  2004    2005   2006

1   480535  507249  505093
2   436113  448323  469148
3   369864  400744  408967
4   346752  340577  367582
5   311091  321042  312671
6   289641  288482  296641
7   273509  270098  267352
8   249395  255649  251337
9   218311  233892  238571
10  205156  205430  218849
```

I'd like to project the next state of the PDF (or to be more accurate of the frequency distribution). The issue is when I simply use linear regression for each age row and simply project forward, I get wild results and the distribution does not hold its form, especially since in the next yearly projection, say for 2007 in our dataset example, some of the members will have died off, left the system (let's say it's a classroom of students) and other things, so not ALL students from 2006 will make it to 2007.

Does anyone know of a method (and it would be nice to suggest a package or a library, but not necessary) that would help me make good projections based on this data set? Like I mentioned projecting linearly for each age gives me weird looking yearly distributions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called [Survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis), and the mathematics behind is a convolution between the new entrants $x(t) = (480535, 507249, 505093)$ and the survival rate $r(t) =$ the probability that someone aged exactly $t$ will survive to age $t+1$.

Basically, you follow cohorts along a diagonal: out of 480535 entrant (age=1) in 2004 survive 448323 (age=2) in 2005 and 408967 (age=3) in 2006... By transforming this into ratio: you get the survival rate $r(1) \approx \frac {448323} {480535} =0.93297$, and $r(2)\approx \frac {448323} {480535}=0.9122$.

Of course, these are observation of the 2004 cohort, and you also have observation of the 2005 cohort, which gives you a slightly different estimates for $r(2) \approx $. And you also have traces of the 2003 cohorts, that will give you an other estimates for $r(2) \approx \frac {400744} {436113} = 0.9189$.
Doing the computations on the whole data will gives you the following survial rates:

```
    2004    2005
2   0.9327  0.9249  
3   0.9189  0.9122
4   0.9208  0.9172
5   0.9259  0.9181
6   0.9273  0.9240
7   0.9325  0.9268
8   0.9347  0.9305
9   0.9378  0.9332
10  0.9410  0.9357
```

You can then make a regression to estimate $r(t)$. For example, you can take $r(t)=0.9058 + 0.0033 \cdot t$. With an exception $r(1)=0.9289$ because the survival rate on the first year seams a little bit higher. Of course if you have more data, you can notice thing like the survival rate is decreasing with time.

The you just have to multiply the 2006 column by this survival rates to get the 2007 forecast. For example $469231.4 = $505093 \cdot 0.9289$ and $429598.8=469148 \cdot r(2) = 469148 \cdot (0.9058 + 0.0033 \cdot 2)$.

Naturally the entrants in 2007 result form a different forecast method (not shown here).

```
      2004    2005    2006    2007
1   480535  507249  505093  
2   436113  448323  469148  469231.4
3   369864  400744  408967  429598.8
4   346752  340577  367582  375840.7
5   311091  321042  312671  339020.9
6   289641  288482  296641  289408.3
7   273509  270098  267352  275549.8
8   249395  255649  251337  249225.5
9   218311  233892  238571  235125.8
10  205156  205430  218849  223970.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

For 2007,

Age 1 = (480535 + 507249 + 505093)/3

Age 2 = 505093*469148/50729

Age 3 = 469148*408967/448323

...

Maybe this method will give you the reasonable frequency.

Comment: Thank you. That helped with the worst point estimates, but still - the distribution doesn't really hold its form, but this is closer to the right answer I think.